# Unable to locate global value from helm subchart

Tags: templates, kubernetes-helm

This is my first time using nested Helm charts and I'm trying to access a global value from the root values.yaml file. [According to the documentation](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/subcharts_and_globals/#global-chart-values) I should be able to use the syntax below in my `secret.yaml` file, however if I run `helm template api --debug` I get the following error:

> Error: template: api/templates/secret.yaml:7:21: executing "api/templates/secret.yaml" at <.Values.global.sa_json>: nil pointer evaluating interface {}.sa_json
> helm.go:84: [debug] template: api/templates/secret.yaml:7:21: executing "api/templates/secret.yaml" at <.Values.global.sa_json>: nil pointer evaluating interface {}.sa_json

**/primaryChart/charts/api/templates/secret.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: {{ .Chart.Name }}-service-account-secret
type: Opaque
data:
  sa_json: {{ .Values.global.sa_json }}
```

**primaryChart/values.yaml**

```
global:
  sa_json: _b64_sa_credentials
```

Folder structure is as follows:

```
/primaryChart 
|- values.yaml 
|-- /charts
    |-- /api
       |-- /templates
           |- secret.yaml
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having the following directory layout, `.Values.global.sa_json` will only be available if you call `helm template api .` from your main chart

```
/mnt/c/home/primaryChart> tree
.
├── Chart.yaml  <-- your main chart
├── charts
│   └── api
│       ├── Chart.yaml  <-- your subchart
│       ├── charts
│       ├── templates
│       │   └── secrets.yaml
│       └── values.yaml
├── templates
└── values.yaml   <--- this is where your global.sa_json is defined
```

Your [values file](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/values_files/) should be called `values.yaml` and not `value.yaml`, or  use any other file with `-f` flag `helm template api . -f value.yaml`

```
/mnt/c/home/primaryChart> helm template api .
---
# Source: primaryChart/charts/api/templates/secrets.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: api-service-account-secret
type: Opaque
data:
  sa_json: _b64_sa_credentials
```

Comment: Sorry - the 'value.yaml' was just a typo, the file is called 'values.yaml.' Also just a quick correction: I tried running `helm template api` from the main chart directory and I need to specify `charts/api` in order to get it to run (it spit back out an error saying `failed to download "api" (hint: running 'helm repo update' may help)`. Unfortunately  after running `helm template charts/api` I'm still getting the error from the original post.

Comment: @NealR you need to specify the primary chart location which equals to `.` (dot) because that's where your `values.yaml` file with `global.sa_json` is - `helm template .`, when you specify  `charts/api` location, this chart does not know that it's a subchart and has to look at other values files besides his proper